# R cor(), method="pearson" returns NA, but method="spearman" returns value. Why?

Tags: r, correlation

I am using R to run correlations on a very large data matrix with approximate dimension 10,000 x 15,000 (events x samples). This data set contains floating point values ranging from -15:15, NA, NaN, inf, and -inf. To simplify the problem I have chosen to work with two rows of my matrix at a time, call them vector1, vector2. The commands are written below:

```
CorrelationSpearman = cor(vector1,vector2, method="spearman",use="pairwise.complete.obs")
CorrelationPearson = cor(vector1,vector2,method="pearson",use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

For most but not all row vectors in my matrix, I get CorrelationPearson=NA. There seems to be no problem with with CorrelationSpearman values. I have checked that the matrix dimensions are correct, and I've run tests on smaller data which work fine. What are some possible reasons why this occurs?

Comment: The `Inf` will cause a problem with `Pearson's`. Check `cor(c(1:3, Inf), 1:4, method="pearson"); cor(c(1:3, Inf), 1:4, method="spearman")`. I assume `Spearman's` is ok as `Inf` can be ranked

Answer (score 3):

The [Pearson correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) relies on estimating means and (co)variance.
Infinite values lead to infinite means and infinite variances, which break computations.
[Spearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Kendall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) correlation coefficients are rank-based, and thus handle sorting just fine with infinite values (but beware of tied values in your samples!).

Try:

```
> lix <- is.infinite(vector1) | is.infinite(vector2)
> cor(vector1[!lix], vector2[!lix], method = "pearson", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

This just plucks out any pair with infinite values.
To do this more generally, a function like this is helpful:

```
> inf2NA <- function(x) { x[is.infinite(x)] <- NA; x }
> cor(inf2NA(vector1), inf2NA(vector2), ...)
```

which just converts infinite values to NAs, and then your `use` argument can handle those NA cases as you see fit.